# Bootstrap grid flow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I need the Bootstrap grid flow in  top to bottom way i.e. in a vertical manner.

ex. if there are total of 15 col then it should adjust like 8 col on left side and 7 col on right side

ie 1 to 8 col should be on the left side and 9 to 15 I should align at the right side.

And also if the no of col is increased it should be balance on the both sides,
 ex. if no of col increased to 17 the it should balance like 1 to 9 on left side and 10 to 17 on right side

Thanks,
Vignesh